# Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 MATLAB boot error GLIBCXX_3.4.11 not found

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, glibc, maple

I upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, now when I run matlab from the command prompt I get (it worked fine on 12.04)

```
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ matlab
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 1: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libut.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwfl.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwmcr.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwm_dispatcher.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwm_interpreter.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwi18n.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libboost_regex.so.1.44.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwmlutil.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libboost_serialization.so.1.44.0)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwiqm.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmex.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwm_parser.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwgui.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwprofiler.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: /usr/local/src/maple18/bin.IBM_INTEL_LINUX/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libmwbinder.so)
```

Please explain how I may resolve this issue. I have searched other posts with similar problems, but they tend to be to do with compiling mex code, so I think they already have matlab running.

***UPDATE***
I have just noticed that in the error message there is a reference to a maple directory. I should point out that I recently installed Maple, prior to the Ubuntu upgrade, and during installation I ticked an option to allow interaction between Maple and MATLAB. I am not sure if I ran MATLAB successfully after installing Maple, but before upgrading Ubuntu. I think I did. I do not care about the Maple MATLAB interfacing, so I am also happy with any solution that removes their dependence.

Comment: Before someone points out the obvious, I rebut: It is not by choice, but by cooperative necessity that I use either proprietary softwares--MATLAB/Maple. If everyone used Sage, and Python life would be easy ;-)

Comment: there is a broken link that you need to repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was because when I installed Maple it installed the Maple Toolbox for MATLAB. When I removed the Maple toolbox MATLAB booted again fine.

First go to your MATLAB root installation, and navigate to the uninstall Maple toolbox directory

`anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/Uninstall_MapleToolbox`

NoW inside the uninstall maple toolbox directory, run the uninstaller

`anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/Uninstall_MapleToolbox$ sudo ./uninstall`

Now running MATLAB works fine

`anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ matlab
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 1: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib/libc.so.6: not found`

Although note there is an error message. MATLAB runs fine so I am not sure if this is of import, but it might be related to me following the repair link [answer by NKN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26341239/3371413) (I issued `anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6.` If someone thinks this is a problem and could advice me how to undo the link I made, that would be great)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following library:

`/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6`

Either you missed it or there is another version of it in your folder.
First try to find it and then re-link it as follows:

```
sudo ln -sf  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6
```

for 64-bit version:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

in the above-mentioned example, the existing library is `libstdc++.so.6.0.16` that I could find using `locate libstdc++.so.6` command on terminal.

check more details [here](http://sgpsproject.sourceforge.net/JavierVGomez/index.php/Solving_issues_with_GLIBCXX_and_libstdc%2B%2B).

Comment: `anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6.` 
Still leaves me with the same problem.